# Posição do Elemento Antes de Arrastar - Droppable - jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Estou fazendo um jogo e preciso pegar a posição de um elemento antes de arrastá-lo. Estou usando a função **Droppable** do jQuery UI.

jQuery

```
$("div.cesto").off().droppable({
    accept : "span.piece",
    // Quando coloca o mouse em cima do cesto
    over : function(){
        $(this).addClass("amp");
        media.replay("boeing-02");
        media.play("boeing-02");
    },
    // Quando sai com o mouse de cima do cesto
    out : function(){
        $(this).removeClass("amp");
    },
    drop : function(event, ui){
        var cesto = $(this);

        // Posições atual do elemento
        var positionTopPiece  = ui.position.top;
        var positionLeftPiece = ui.position.left;
```

Nas duas últimas linhas do código notem que estou pegando a posição atual do elemento. Ou seja, eu clico sobre o elemento, arrasto e solto e me dá a posição.

Mas não é isso o que eu quero. Eu quero que ao clicar no elemento, antes de arrastá-lo, guarde a sua posição **TOP** e **LEFT** para usar posteriormente em uma função.

Isto é, o elemento vai voltar para sua posição de origem dependendo de um resultado.

Estou na documentação do **Droppable** - http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/

Mas não encontro uma função que faça o que preciso.

---

**position**

Type: Object

Current CSS position of the draggable helper as { top, left } object.

**offset**

Type: Object

Current offset position of the draggable helper as { top, left } object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, usando o *callback* **activate**.

```
    // Ao clicar sobre o elemento 
    activate : function(event, ui){
        positionTopPiece  = ui.draggable.css("top"); // Posição de Origem - Para caso errar, voltar
        positionLeftPiece = ui.draggable.css("left"); // Posição de Origem - Para caso errar, voltar
    },
```

Criei duas variáveis globais. 
`positionTopPiece`e `positionLeftPiece`.

Pego as posições **top** e **left** e depois uso em uma função para voltar o item à sua origem.

Obrigado.